# Hashtable of type <String,String> is storing <String, Integer> type value as I see in the log cat and debugger. Is it possible?

Tags: java, android, hashtable

This is my first question I am posting here. Since You guys have already answered so many question and generally I find answers, thanks to stackoverflow.
So being specific to my problem-
I have an static `Hastable` with a type `<String,String>`. When I am setting the values and key from some other activity, in some specific case(I am not sure of the case) my `Hastable` is having data of type `<String, Integer>`. I checked in debugger its also showing the same. What mistake I have made can anyone please help me pointing the issues?
Thanks.

**Edit**
This was my code-

```
       Hashtable<String,String> details;
        details= new Hashtable<>();
        Hashtable temp;
        temp = details;
        temp.put("key1", new Integer("1"));
        temp.put("key2", "1");
        Log.d("details", details.get("key1"));//Causes ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        Log.d("temp",temp.get("key1").toString());//No issue ,worked
```

Comment: without looking at the code it'd be difficult to tell you what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: OK, Is it possible ? Can a Hashtable of type <String,String> contains value of type <String, Integer>? @Aman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a `Hashtable` of type `<String,String>` contains value of type `<String, Integer>`

Yes it is possible.  The actual runtime typing for the `Hashtable` uses `Object` as the key and value types.  (For a longer explanation Google "java type erasure" ...)

For example, when you write this:

```
 Hashtable<String, String> tab = new Hashtable<>();
 tab.put("A", "B");
 String res = tab.get("A");
```

the last statement is really doing this under the covers:

```
 String res = (String) tab.get("A");
```

If you have played by the rules, then the typecast can never fail.

> What mistake I have made can anyone please help me pointing the issues?

Without seeing your code we can only guess, but one possible explanation is that you have ignored (or suppressed) a critical "unchecked conversion" warning or similar.  For example:

```
 Hashtable<String, Integer> tab = new Hashtable<>();
 tab.put("A", new Integer(42));

 // Unchecked conversion
 Hashtable<String, String> bad = (Hashtable<String, String>) tab;

 String res = bad.get("A");    // Ooops!
```

You should never just ignore compiler warnings. Sometimes it is safe to suppress them, but you really need to understand what they mean to make that judgement. If you just suppress them without due consideration, you are liable to write buggy code that throws ClassCastException in unexpected places.

Comment: I found the issue before your answer , but since your answer is to the point , I accepted. I was not aware of this behaviour of generics.

Comment: Exactly same problem I was facing, Great answer. Everything explained, I googled and read the type erasure in detail after the answer of @Crazyjavahacking .

Comment: On My machine Java hotspot 7 and mac this does not compile with cast error ?.See the same here http://ideone.com/UKeJ2j

Answer (score 1):

**In Java generics are implemented using type erasure.**

`Hashtable` is able to store any kind of keys and values. So in theory it is possible. The IDE might guess the type based on the actual values.

Comment: Your answer helped me to find the issue in the code due to type erasure behaviour of generics.
Your answer deserves up - vote.